# Angular - include .ts file from local custom npm module (installed)

Tags: angular, typescript

**question**: how to let Angular look inside the `node_modules` folder instead of the 'custom directory defined in package.json' when including files from a custom npm-module. (see package.json below)

---

In my project i have 2 folders

- root

  - angular

    - src
    - package.json
  - shared (npm module)

    - src
    - package.json

within the directory of ***angular***, i install my custom npm module through the normal `npm install`. here is the package.json file

```
 {
  "name": "angular",
  "dependencies": {
    "shared-module": "file:../shared-module"
  }
```

i can see its installed correctly by checking the node_modules folder of the ***angular*** directory

- root

  - angular

    - node_modules

      - shared-module

        - src

then when I include a file from the ***shared-module*** in the ***angular*** project

```
import 'shared-module/src/util/countries';
```

it doesn't seem to look inside the angular->node_modules folder, but instead keeps going to the 'original' directory of the custom npm module ..

> ERROR in ../shared-module/src/util/countries.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

if I update the tsconfig.json to include the 'original' directory, it works..

```
"include": [
  "./src/**/*.ts",
  "../shared-modules//src/**/*.ts"
]
```

But then there is no real point adding it to the package.json with (unless you publish the module)

```
"shared-module": "file:../shared-module"
```

So it feels like I am missing some settings maybe? Thanks in advance

---

edit: it seems ***NPM 5*** creates a symlink when using it like this

```
"shared-modules": "file:../shared-module"
```

---

edit2: ***preserveSymlinks*** doesn't seem to do anything (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

anyway around that behavior and just ***really install*** the package?

Comment: What did you use to build the custom module?

Comment: Don't know if I understand the question, but I used nothing to build.. Use-case: the angular project includes some .ts files from custom module and uses these files to compile / build an Angular output.. The shared folder does not need to be 'pre-build'

Comment: Okay I misunderstood. I thought you were installing a custom-packed npm module into your app.

Comment: Ah yes that is correct :) I have to work on my SO skills, i'm sorry (second post or so).. The module is installed correctly, but when I import a file from the module, it doesn't go to the node_modules folder, but instead to the 'original' path of the custom_module, and thus brakes the scope of the folder.. question is: how to let typescript NOT follow the symlink and instead treat is a 'local' module from the angular own node_module folder? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

When I work with uncompiled libraries that I might want to edit and have angular pick up changes right away, I add them to "paths" of tsconfig or use "npm link"

Comment: Thanks but I want to avoid npm link (NPM 5 does npm-link by default when using install file../my-module). It would be nice if the package is really installed locally, so I keep all files in the 'angular' directory scope ...  (also using docker)